# Problem getting php7.4-fpm to start on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, fpm, php-7.4

I am using nginx, and not apache. Just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and thus php7.2 to php7.4.
However php7.4-fpm fails to start. This is my log.

```
ian@thebeb:/etc/php/7.4/fpm$ sudo /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart
Restarting php7.4-fpm (via systemctl): php7.4-fpm.serviceJob for php7.4-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
ian@thebeb:/etc/php/7.4/fpm$ systemctl status php7.4-fpm.service
● php7.4-fpm.service - The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-01-17 21:01:20 GMT; 9s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm7.4(8)
    Process: 63191 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=127)
    Process: 63205 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 74 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 63191 (code=exited, status=127)

Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb php-fpm7.4[63191]: /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4: undefined symbol: pcre2_set_depth_limit_8
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager.
ian@thebeb:/etc/php/7.4/fpm$ journalctl -xe
-- A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 431.
Jan 17 21:01:10 thebeb dbus-daemon[3745]: [session uid=1000 pid=3745] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=3742 >
Jan 17 21:01:10 thebeb dbus-daemon[3745]: [session uid=1000 pid=3745] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Jan 17 21:01:10 thebeb systemd[3723]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 431.
Jan 17 21:01:15 thebeb kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp0s3 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:bc:14:01:0f:f6:e6:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb sudo[63180]:      ian : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/etc/php/7.4/fpm ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb sudo[63180]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager...
-- Subject: A start job for unit php7.4-fpm.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit php7.4-fpm.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3745.
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb php-fpm7.4[63191]: /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4: undefined symbol: pcre2_set_depth_limit_8
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit php7.4-fpm.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: php7.4-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit php7.4-fpm.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager.
-- Subject: A start job for unit php7.4-fpm.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit php7.4-fpm.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 3745 and the job result is failed.
Jan 17 21:01:20 thebeb sudo[63180]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 17 21:01:41 thebeb tracker-store[63047]: OK
Jan 17 21:01:41 thebeb systemd[3723]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
ian@thebeb:/etc/php/7.4/fpm$
```

The symbol lookup error, was symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4: undefined symbol: pcre2_set_depth_limit_8.

I have checked everything I can think of, and can't spot the problem. Now I am out of my depth! Help.

Added after request:

```
ian@thebeb:/etc/php/7.4/fpm$ ldd $(which php-fpm7.4)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffefb4e7000)
    libargon2.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libargon2.so.1 (0x00007f13e38a6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f13e388a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f13e373b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f13e3735000)
    libapparmor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1 (0x00007f13e3720000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f13e3671000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f13e34b5000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f13e3422000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f13e2f57000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f13e2d0c000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f13e2af0000)
    libsodium.so.23 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.23 (0x00007f13e2a98000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f13e28a4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f13e2881000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f13e3d6f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f13e2876000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f13e284d000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f13e282c000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f13e270e000)
    libicuuc.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66 (0x00007f13e2526000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f13e2503000)
    libicudata.so.66 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.66 (0x00007f13e0a42000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f13e0861000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f13e0846000)
ian@thebeb:/etc/php/7.4/fpm$
```

Comment: Show output of `ldd $(which php-fpm7.4)`

Answer (score 1):

`pcre2_set_depth_limit_8` is a library symbol reference (on my system it is in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so`) that appears, again on my system, to reside in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.10.0`.

So, I suspect that the PCRE package on *your* system is damaged. Check the status of your `libpcre2-8-0` package.

Or just do

```
ldd /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 | grep pcre2
```

and check where it points, or if it says that the library was not found (in the latter case you just need to apt-get install it, and apparently the dependency check system for that library is broken, since it didn't spot the lack).

If it *does* point to a .so file, then let's check said file: for example (I have only a Raspberry available)

```
 nm -gD  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre2-8.so.0.7.1
```

should report all the symbols in the library, and grep'ping for ours *does* find it:

```
 0000f508 T pcre2_set_depth_limit_8
```

If it did **not**, then that would mean that the library does not contain the symbol -- which to me indicates that the library has to be somehow damaged, since on other systems that symbol *is* there.

## Ubuntu 20.04

I remembered I *had* a 20.04 available somewhere else. The library there is `libpcre2-8.so.0.9.0`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 584392 Dec  7  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.9.0
```

and the symbol *is* there. The Ubuntu package I have is `libpcre2-8-0:amd64`.

```
 # nm -gD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.9.0 | grep pcre2_set_depth_limit_8
 00000000000116f0 T pcre2_set_depth_limit_8
```

Comment: The file points to -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  883104 Feb 23  2017 libpcre2-8.so.0.3.0
 in /usr/local/lib.  Have reinstalled.

Comment: It appears that an install of 20.04 puts libpcre2-8.so.0.9.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, but upgrading installs the same, and then attempts to use /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.3.0, which exists, but does not have the right symbols.  And I can't remove it, because this would leave lots of broken depends.

Comment: Try running "ldconfig -v" and see whether this fixes the dependencies. Otherwise I think packages can be forcefully reinstalled if the versions do not match.